# RDF is it possible to make properties from other ontologies?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege

I have a predicates and I put an annotation for it like this:

[image]

Is it possible to do the same considering that `degreeBy` comes from another ontology?

I am using protoge and looking at the actually ontology i find this

```
<!-- http://www.bla.com/2016/03/01/rs#degreeBy -->

<owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http:/blablabla.com/2016/03/01/rs#degreeBy"/>
```

and i also find this

```
 <!-- http://www.bla bla bla.com/2016/03/01/rs#belongsTo -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.bla bla bla.com/2016/03/01/rs#belongsTo">
        <degreeBy rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.5</degreeBy>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
```

what i would like to do is to have **IN AnOTHER ONTOLOGY** a data property that the range is double, and then use that property as a property (maybe the correct name is annotation not property) for the `belongsTo` property

can i please ? i am using protoge,

Comment: No property can have xsd:double as its domain, since a double is a literal and a literal can't be a subject of a triple.

Comment: I believe that's an error in the question, and Ania meant to write range there, not domain.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor i meant range,  corrected now

Answer (score 2):

To achieve your purpose in Protege you have to import the other ontology.

If you wish to use the same property without importing the defining ontology, then you have to declare a property of the same type and with the exact same IRI (the mamespaces must match) in your ontology. However this will lose domain and range axioms.

Note: In order to use literals of type `xsd:double` you'll use range axioms, not domain axioms as suggested in your initial post.

Comment: I'm wondering whether it's possible to use a data property as an annotation property? I know that  the set of object and data properties have to be disjoint.

Comment: Most tools will not complain but the ontology will be owl full

Comment: Okay I imported the two ontologies, and now i can see the classes and properties from both of them. However, i don't know how to use a data property from one ontolgoy to a object property from the other ontolgoies, when i click add annotation on the object property, the data property didn't show at all.

Comment: That's because you cannot 'pun' properties in OWL 2 DL - you're trying to use a data property as an annotation property. Protégé is stopping you from violating owl constraints.

Comment: @Ignazio could you help please ?

Comment: It does not work with Protege and he already explained why. The sets of object, data and annotation properties are supposed to be disjoint in OWL 2 DL and Protege, otherwise you would be in OWL full which is not a problem at all - given that you do not want to do reasoning - but in Protege only annotation properties are shown up for annotations.